# QDMA DPDK driver results "Packet Length Mismatch" Error during data transfer

Tags: xilinx, dpdk, pci, vfio, dpdk-pmd

I am new to DPDK and QDMA. I am using alveo u200 with OpenNIC. I have bind the interface with VFIO-PCI driver. While executing Pktgen/TestPMD Application I am getting "*Packet Length mismatch Error*".

Please let me know what is the cause for this issue.

Comment: @Nafiul Alam Fuji, please let me why the re is "Packet Length Mismatch". Do I need to increase any parameter values?

Comment: I haven't gone far with QDMA but please share more details of your problem so that others with appropriate knowledge can help. please tell the details which version of OS/DPDK/Others are you using, a little glimpse how you installed DPDK, and then what was your goal and how you got the error when approached. thanks..!

Comment: Hi @NafiulAlamFuji. Thanks for the reply. I am using Rhel8 OS, DPDK 20.11, Pktgen applciation version 21.03. I was following the OpenNIC DPDK gitpage https://github.com/Xilinx/open-nic-dpdk/. I wanted to test the throughput using pktgen application. OpenNIC supports 100Gbps of throughput, but I could receive 40Gbps with "Packet Length Mismatch Error" during test. This error hinders receive of data packets at receiver.